# How to match a complete string containing unicode characters?

Tags: regex, go, re2

I want to validate a string for e.g. name. A string without spaces. For normal Ascii a following regex would suffice "^\w+$" where ^ and $ takes the whole string into consideration.  I tried to achieve the same result for unicode characters for supporting multiple languages using the \pL character class. But for some reason $ doesn't help match end of string. What am I doing wrong?

Code sample is here: https://play.golang.org/p/SPDEbWmqx0N

I copy pasted random characters from: http://www.columbia.edu/~fdc/utf8/

go version **go1.12.5 darwin/amd64**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    // Unicode character class

    fmt.Println(regexp.MatchString(`^\pL+$`, "testuser"))  // expected true
    fmt.Println(regexp.MatchString(`^\pL+$`, "user with space")) // expected false 


    // Hindi script
    fmt.Println(regexp.MatchString(`^\pL+$`, "सकता")) // expected true doesn't match end of line

    // Hindi script
    fmt.Println(regexp.MatchString(`^\pL+`, "सकता")) // expected true

    // Chinese
    fmt.Println(regexp.MatchString(`^\pL+$`, "我能")) // expected true

    //French
    fmt.Println(regexp.MatchString(`^\pL+$`, "ægithaleshâtifs")) // expected true 

}
```

```
actual result:
true  <nil>
false <nil>
false <nil>
true <nil>
true <nil>
true <nil>

expected result:
true <nil>
false <nil>
true <nil>
true <nil>
true <nil>
true <nil>
```

Comment: If you really want to check for "a string without spaces" you can do that with `strings.ContainsAny` or `strings.IndexFunc`. E.g. https://play.golang.org/p/oTCqcPrJkcb

Comment: I stripped down the problem to illustrate the issue I was facing w.r.t end of line. Basically needed to use \pM as mentioned in the answer below. I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^[\p{L}\p{M}]+$
```

See [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/3dGZZQgnx68).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[` -  start of a character class that matches

  - `\p{L}` - any BMP letter
  - `\p{M}` - any diacritic
- `]+` - end of the character class, repeat 1+ times
- `$` - end of string.

If you plan to also match digits and `_` as `\w` does, add them to the character class, `^[\p{L}\p{M}0-9_]+$` or `^[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]+$`.